# Show and serialize the results of select_related() model method

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

I have two simple models:
User (standard Django User)
AND
class Post (models.Model):

```
class Post (models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

My front end (SPA) sends a request to get all posts, so my Django API would go and fetch Post.objects.all(). However I would like to also pull in the User.username into the response. My understanding is that I can do this by running:

```
posts=Post.objects.select_related('user').all()
```

When I run `posts.query` from the resulting SQL query I can see that the User fields are being pulled in, however I can't seem to be able to see them when I try to serialize this data. Am I missing something very basic here? What is the way to serialize the related data together with the parent data and send it out with the DRF Response?
I have tried approach described in this article, but the serializer built with this approach does not seem to return related data for me:
http://ses4j.github.io/2015/11/23/optimizing-slow-django-rest-framework-performance/

Answer (score 4):

```py
PostSerializer():
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('name', 'user')
```

Comment: This worked. I also had another Model related to Post through user (UserProfile). Had to add UserProfileSerializer field into UserSerializer to get the full tree. Thank you.

Comment: I am pleased to. Good luck)